# list allows duplicates but how to write logic to dis-allow duplicates in list in core java

Tags: java

List allows duplicates but write logic to dis-allow duplicates in list

```
import  java.util.*;
class ALTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList al=new ArrayList();
        al.add("A");
        al.add("B");
        al.add("A");
        al.add(10);
        al.add(20);
        al.add("List");
        System.out.println(al);
    }
}
```

here A is duplicated it should not be duplicate

Comment: What do you mean by write logic? If you don't want to allow duplicates, look into a `Set`.

Comment: use `Set` if you want to disallow duplicates, when functionality is already present why to take pains and write something new

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way is to use a LinkdHashSet instead. It will prevent duplicates, and you can still iterate over the elements in the same order they were added to the Set.

Comment: no wonder how others get such huge amount of reputations?!!! you easily could flag this either as a duplicate post or too broad

Answer (score 0):

You have to ensure that no duplicates are entered. If you want to use a list strictly then implement a searching algorithm to find whether the element exist within the list before entering it. If you a thinking of different data structure I will suggest you

- HashSet
- Tree Set

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
ArrayList al=new ArrayList();
```

To

```
Set al = new HashSet();
```

Or use LinkedHashset, as Eran suggested, if you care about insertion order.

** Linked typically means that each element contains a reference to the next element, which by default in JCF typically implies insertion order.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write your own `List`, you can always extend an existing `List` class and add the logic needed:

```
public class MyList<T> extends ArrayList<T> {
    @Override
    public boolean add(T item) {
        if (!this.contains(item)) {
            return (super.add(item));
        }
        return (false);
    }
}
```

(The example is incomplete, it only serves to show the general principle)